# How to synchronize tasks on multiple computers

Tags: windows, sync, lan, video-streaming, tasks

I would like to be able to run similar tasks on several computers that must be precisely synced. More specifically I need 4 laptops to be synced, probably over local network, and I need to use one of them to start a task (play a video) on all of them at the same time (different video files on different laptops). All of them are running Windows. Is there a third-party software or any easier way to do so over LAN without significant delay? I need virtually no response time - if there would be a single video streaming on all laptops then people should not recognize the delay.

Comment: To what tolerance?  Have you tested to see how many ms you can get away with?  Exact sync is not possible, so you should determine what is tolerable

Comment: @Paul I guess I don't need perfect sync, there is a small tolerance, but no more than 100ms. That should be possible via lan.

Comment: Maybe use [Sysinternal's Psexec](http://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx) in the way [explained at Sysinternals forum](http://forum.sysinternals.com/psexec-multiple-pc_topic4473.html): `psexec @PClistfile -u admin -p passw -e -d cmd_to_run`. If this approach is working for you, I would consider a fully explained answer. Until then, its a shot in the dark

Comment: Does it have to be Windows?  I think NTP will get clocks close enough, but loading a video file can be impacted by all kinds of things.  Put it local, ssd, and use a stripped back linux box with just a window manager and vlc/mplayer

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to go the streaming route, there is another option.

In *nix's you have nice things like [SSH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Shell) that can be used to send a command to play the video from the local drive almost instantly. Write a simple script, and all four computers could start almost exactly the same time, without the overhead and delay of streaming over the network, because they would be playing files on their hard drive.

You could maybe hack together a solution by installing [sshwindows](http://sshwindows.sourceforge.net/) on the "slave" computers and then using [Cygwin](http://cygwin.com/) on the "master" to run the script, but it would require some (very) basic knowledge of the commands.

From my understanding, Window's Remote Desktop wouldn't work in this situtation because you can't use it just to send a single command like you can with SSH. (Feel free to correct me, Windows people)